# How to convert polynominal to general form

Tags: python

I am having trouble with an algorithm which will convert polynominal from factor form `( (x-1)(x+5)(x-9) )` to general form `( x^3 -5x^2 -41x +45)`. At the start I have only a list of roots

For example: `[1, -5, 9]`

The output should be a list of coefficients: `[1, -5, -41, 45]`

Any ideas how I can work this out?

```
def przeksztalc(wielomian):
    pierwiastki = []
    for i in wielomian:
        lista_pomocniacza = []
        lista_pomocniacza.append(i * (-1))
        lista_pomocniacza.append(1)
        pierwiastki.append(lista_pomocniacza)
    rezultat = dzielenie_na_pary(pierwiastki)
    return rezultat


def dzielenie_na_pary(lista_z_pierwiastkami):
    dlugosc = len(lista_z_pierwiastkami)
    wynik = []
    for i in range(dlugosc-1):
        wynik = mnozenie_nawiasow(lista_z_pierwiastkami[i], lista_z_pierwiastkami[i+1])
        lista_z_pierwiastkami[i+1] = wynik
    return wynik[::-1]


def mnozenie_nawiasow(nawias1, nawias2):
    wynik_mnozenia = [0] * (len(nawias1 + nawias2) - 1)
    for i in range(len(nawias1)):
        for j in range(len(nawias2)):
            wynik_mnozenia[i+j] += nawias1[i] * nawias2[j]
    return wynik_mnozenia

wielomian = [1, -5, 9]
print(przeksztalc(wielomian))
```

Comment: Stackoverflow is for helping you *after* you seriously attempt to write a program and have a problem.

Comment: But i dont have idea how to start. I need some advise.

Comment: Start by doing a few examples by hand. What do you do? Try to turn your manual algorithm into a software algorithm.

The way I would approach this problem is by making an observation about how each individual coefficient comes from the list of roots. (each can be computed independently)

Comment: Lookup polynomial multiplication.  For instance, https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra2/arithmetic-with-polynomials/multiplying-polynomials-review/v/more-multiplying-polynomials is about multiple a general polynomial by a binomial, which all you need for this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  You need to write a function that takes two lists, which are the coefficients of a polynomial, in order.  For general use, I suggest that you go lowest to highest.  That would make your known roots appear as

[-1, 1]
[5, 1]
[-9, 1]

The routine simply works through a nested loop, one index for each list.  The product of coefficients i (in one list) and j (in the other) get added to coefficient i+j in the result.

Use this repeatedly to build a running product.  Call it once with ([-1, 1], [5, 1]) to get the result [-5, 4, 1].  Call it again with that and the last root to get your final answer.

Does that get you moving?

Comment: That's great to hear!  Can you add your solution to my posting?  That would really help complete the answer.

Comment: how can i add solution to ur post? And names of variables are in polish leangue its ok for u?

Comment: Ah.  You do not have enough reputation to edit my answer.  Perhaps post an answer of your own, and I will add your code to mine.  Polska is good for me.  I may translate your variable names as I go, since SO is supposed to be in English.  Djiekuje!